# Convert number to alphabet string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

I want to convert a number to a char like:

- if number = 1 then A
- if number = 26 then Z
- if number = 27 then AA
- if number = 676 then ZZ
- if number = 456976 then ZZZZ

Tried to find anything to help me with but I did not had any lucky. Anybody have a sample for this using JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: what about `0`? *(how)* do you convert that?

Comment: This makes no sense. Is it only to be done with A and Z? Or were those just "corner case examples"? How would you get AB? DE? XYZ?

Comment: Where is the logic here ( 26 + 1 == AA ) && (26 * 26 == ZZ) ?

Answer (score 16):

The number conversion you've shown doesn't seem consistent. It seems you want to convert a number to the equivalent spreadsheet column letter, similar to this Python question: [*Convert spreadsheet number to column letter*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861680/convert-spreadsheet-number-to-column-letter).

Converting that code to javascript (and cleaning up a bit) gives:

```js
function numToSSColumn(num){
  var s = '', t;

  while (num > 0) {
    t = (num - 1) % 26;
    s = String.fromCharCode(65 + t) + s;
    num = (num - t)/26 | 0;
  }
  return s || undefined;
}


// A  Z AA  CZ  DA  YZ  ZZ AAA
[0,1,26,27,104,105,676,702,703,
//AAZ ABA  AZZ  BAA  BAZ  BBA   YYYZ   ZZZZ
  728,729,1378,1379,1404,1405,456976,475254].forEach(function(n) {
  console.log(n + ' : ' + numToSSColumn(n));
});
```

The function doesn't check the input and returns *undefined* if `n < 0`.

Your conversions don't seem to work because spreadsheet columns don't start from 0, they start from 1, so A-Z is 1 to 26, AA to AZ is 27 to 52, and so on. 676 is YZ and 456976 is YYYZ. ZZZZ is 475254 (or 11110 base26);

Answer (score 7):

You will need to write a loop, and mod (%) the number by 26 each time through and use the following:

```
 String.fromCharCode(num + 64) // if num is 1 then result is 'A'
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a solution using recursion, well... just for fun really :)

```js
const numberToBase26 = (val, tail = '') => {
  if (val <= 26) {
    return `${String.fromCharCode(val + 64)}${tail}`;
  }

  const remainder = val % 26 || 26;
  const division = Math.trunc(val / 26) - (remainder === 26 ? 1 : 0);

  return numberToBase26(division, `${String.fromCharCode(remainder + 64)}${tail}`);
};

console.log(numberToBase26(475254), ' should be equal to ZZZZ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have very weird cases that are hard to understand. if `27 = AA`, then `52 = ZZ` but according to your example `676 = ZZ`. Can you elaborate on the series that you want to generate.
Just in case following is the algorithm that satisfies my example:

```
getAlphabetFromNumber = function (_num) {
    var str = "";

    multiples = Math.ceil(_num / 26);
    _charAtCode = _num - ((multiples - 1) * 26)

    for (let i = 0; i < multiples; i++)
        str += String.fromCharCode(_charAtCode + 64);

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The important part is charCodeAt which returns the ASCII value for any character.

```js
function columnIndex(name) {
    let index = 0;

    name = name.toUpperCase().split('');

    for (let i = name.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let piece = name[i];
        let colNumber = piece.charCodeAt() - 64;
        index = index + colNumber * Number(Math.pow(26, name.length - (i + 1)));
    }

    return index;
}

['A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AAB', 'MMMM', 'MMMN'].forEach((n) => {
    console.log(n + ' : ' + columnIndex(n));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, open your inspector, select console. and paste this in:

`cvt = function(n) {return(String.fromCharCode(n+'A'.charCodeAt(0)-1))}`

Now you can type `cvt(1)` to get 'A', or `cvt(26)` to get 'Z'

It only works for one character. The rest is for you to work out