# How to copy a column in Dataframe for multiple time?

Tags: python, pandas

For example

```
df = {'a': (1,2,3)}
pd.DataFrame(df)
```

and I want to copy the column for several times, and put them in to the same dataframe. I hope it finally becomes

```
    a   b   c
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
```

Codes I tried need manually name the columns. And I cannot build a loop to auto name columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to write by hand the alphabet, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'a': (1,2,3)}
dd = pd.DataFrame(df)

numcopies = 4 #how many copies you want of the original column named 'a'
names = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(1, numcopies+1)]

for n in names:
    dd[n] = dd['a']
```

[chr()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#chr) and [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#ord) are built-in functions which comes in handy to generate sequence of letters / characters.

#### EDIT after comments

A more concise version of it (with no need to store the names in a variable) is:

```
for i in range(1, numcopies+1):
    dd[chr(ord('a') + i)] = dd['a']
```

#### EDIT: column names with more than one character

If you want to have a lot of copied columns, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862195/10426037). It is a good way to produce sequences of  strings longer that 1 character with alphabet letters only based on an input number (so you do not end with strange symbols as name column).

You can do:

```
for i in range(1, numcopies+1):
    dd[colnum_string(i)] = dd['a']
```

where `column_string` is the function defined in the link above.

Comment: No need to store the names. You can do directly.
   `for i in range(10):
        df[chr(ord('a') + i)] = df['a']`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) and [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for an efficient way of doing this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = {'a': (1,2,3)}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

# where n is the number of columns you want
n = 5

df_new = df.assign(**{x: df.iloc[:, 0] for x in ascii_lowercase[:n]})
print(df_new)
```

[output]

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
names = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] #names for the columns
for i in names:
    df[i] = df['a'] #assigns the columns in a loop
```

Comment: thanks very much. But If want to copy 100 times, this code dose not really help as I still have to manually type the name.

Comment: I prefer numbered columns instead of letters, so I would change it to something like this: `names = ['col' + str(i) for i in range(1, x+1, 1)]`. Here x is the number of columns you want.