# obtain header "letter" searching for column name in excel with pandas and python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

im using pandas with excel and i would like to get the letter of the header in excel searching for column name.

here´s an example

[image: 1]

i would like to do something LIKE this: df.columns.get_loc("SR Status") and i would like to return: "D"

i have already done this:

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_excel("file.xls")
df.columns.get_loc("SR Status")
```

and let´s assume data will NOT always be in the same place.
sometimes it might be at header "A" but other time could be on other place
thanks in advance

Comment: Can one assume that the data always begins in column A?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert spreadsheet number to column letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861680/convert-spreadsheet-number-to-column-letter)

Comment: im sorry, let´s assume data will NOT always be in the same column

Comment: If the data doesn't always begin in column A, then AFAIK there is no way to do this in pandas. I'd use openpyxl or xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_column_letter`:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', usecols='D:F')
offset = 4  # D

col = get_column_letter(df.columns.get_loc('SR Status') + offset)
print(col)  # Output: D
```