# Figuring out the number corresponding to a letter of the alphabet?

Tags: c++, excel

I'm trying to duplicate the way excel provides labels its columns where

> A = 1
>   B = 2

so on and so forth, so that it eventually reaches

> AB
>   AC
>   AD

etc, etc.

How  do I algorithmically take a number (like 52) and convert it to its equivalent alphabet representation?

Comment: I do not see why someone should vote to close it? If the question is not clear to one, one may ask for clarification.

Comment: no, its good question +1

Comment: People vote to close only because it isn't exactly formulated as a question. Doh...

Comment: @meds I've rephrased the question a little bit so that the SO lawyers would lose their reason to cast close votes on this question. Cut it out, folks...

Comment: There are many questions asking this for different languages.  Eg see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/667802/445425), asked for C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string get(int a) {
  a--; // Reduce by one to make the values with 1 letter 0..25, 
       // with two - 26.. 26^2-1 and so on
  int val = 0; // number of columns with no more then given number of letters
  int number = 0;
  while (val < a) {
    val = val*26 + 26;
    number++;
  }
  val = (val - 26)/26;
  a -= val; // subtract the number of columns with less letters 
  string res;
  for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
    res.push_back(a%26 + 'A');
    a /= 26;
  }
  reverse(res.begin(), res.end());
  return res;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

for two letters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string int2alphas(int i) {
    string res;
    if (i > 26 - 1)
        res.push_back(i / 26 + 'A' - 1);
    else 
        res.push_back(' ');
    res.push_back(i % 26 + 'A');
    return res;
}

void test(int t) {
    cout << t << "-" << int2alphas(t) << endl;;
}


int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++)
        test(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ToInt32("52", 26).... And now just create the correct base implementation.
? homework ?

Answer (score 1):

You may think of writing some algo like:

```
ConvertToAlphaCode(number input)
{
    Array Chars=[A-Z]
    if (number<= 26)
        return Chars[number-1]
    else
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look:

`A, B, C, D, ..., Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD, ..., AY, AZ, BA, BB, ...`

is exactly like:

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ..., 19, 20, 21, ...`

but with digits `A..Z` instead of `0..9`. So:

> Algorithmic-ally I'm not sure how I can get a number, like say 52, and convert it to the equivalent alphabet representation..

You need to use a generic algorithm to convert a number in base-N to base-M (like decimal to hexadecimal), but with N equal to 10 and M equal to 26 (letters), and make sure that you use correct characters to represent the final "digits". As simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it quite well:

```
string calcString(int number)
{
    string returnValue = "";
    do
    {
        int rm = number % 26;
        returnValue += (char)(rm+ 'A');
        number = (number - rm) / 26;
   } 
   while (number > 0);

   return returnValue;
}
```

For example, `calcString(11);` results in `L`.

If this is not precisely the calculation for which you were looking, leave a comment to clarify what you want and I'll come back to change it.

Comment: Note that the encoding of letters is not guaranteed to be contiguous (although except for IBM mainframes, you're unlikely to encounter an encoding where the 26 unaccented letters aren't contiguous).

Answer (score 0):

From number to letter:

```
static std::string const letters( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" );
assert( n >= 0 && n < letters.size() );
return letters[n];
```

From letter to number:

```
static std::string const letters( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" );
char const* result = std::find(
            letters.begin(),
            letters.end(),
            isupper( static_cast< unsigned char >( l ) );
assert( result != letters.end() );
return result - letters.begin();
```

EDIT:

This just handles a single character in each direction.  For more, it's
just a base 26 conversion, using the usual conversion routine.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with all types of letters (small, big).

```
using namespace std;

int lettervalue (string l) {
    l=l[0];
    string alpha="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int idx = alpha.find(l)+1;
    if(idx>26){
        idx=idx-26;
    }

    return idx;

}
```

To use it:

```
cout << lattervalue("e"); //will return 5(int)
```