# Match Column Int to column letters? or Write to column using Letter Header

Tags: c#, excel

So usually when you write to an excel worksheet it's something like this `oSheet.Cells[1, 2]`  you supply the int row and then supply the column int.

Well I have a config file thats about 70 columns that range from H to CE to DF ect.

How do you write to a column like so?  `oSheet.Cells[1, AF]`?

I hope this makes sense

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the algorithm to convert an Excel Column Letter into its Number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667802/what-is-the-algorithm-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference excel Ranges using A1 notation.  Try something like

```
oSheet.Range("AF1")
```

Then to do this for different letters, you can concatenate

```
Col = "A"
oSheet.Range( Col & "1" )
```

Edit: sorry, realized those should be parens (had square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet.Cells` returns a [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.range%28v=office.15%29.aspx) object.

The [Item/indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.item%28v=office.15%29.aspx) of the Range object *already accepts* Excel-style values for the *column* index. The difference is merely between using an *integer* for the column value, or a *string* for the value.

> [Column index is a] number or string that indicates the column number of the cell you want to access, starting with either 1 [integer] or "A" [string] for the first column in the range.

So, `oSheet.Cells[1, "AF"]` would return the desired result (Range).