# C# How to convert specific lower-case letters to uppercase and uppercase letters to lowercase at the same time

Tags: c#

I want to exchange all occurences of a character in a string with their case-counterpart.

For example:

> "%Y %m %d | %H:%M:%S"

should become

> "%Y %M %d | %H:%m:%S"

for the character 'm' or 'M'.

How can I best do this in C# ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The positions are fixed so pass the string to the ctor of a StringBuilder then you can change by index: sb[4] = 'M'; ...

Comment: Well, my idea is to convert it to a byte array and work on the single characters, converting lowercase 'm' to uppercase and uppercase 'M' to lowercase, but I thought there must be some simpler way to do this.
Thanks for the idea with the StringBuilder, I will try that.

Comment: Enumerate the characters in the string and change them as needed. Then convert that `char[]` to a string

Comment: Try following :             string input = "%Y %m %d | %H:%M:%S";
            string output = string.Join("",input.Select(x => (x == 'm') ? 'M' : (x == 'M') ? 'm' : x));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regexes... there are two possibilities here:

One using two distinct groupings and choosing which grouping was used in the replace function:

```
var rx1 = new Regex("(%M)|(%m)");

string original1 = "%Y %m %d | %H:%M:%S";
string modified1 = rx1.Replace(original1, x => x.Groups[1].Success ? "%m" : "%M");
```

The other simply taking a look in the replace function on what is the matched text.

```
var rx2 = new Regex("%[Mm]");

string original2 = "%Y %m %d | %H:%M:%S";
string modified2 = rx2.Replace(original2, x => x.Value == "%M" ? "%m" : "%M");
```

Just as a curiousity, I'll add two regexes that handle the escaping of a `%` with another `%`: `%m` is month, `%%m` is the string `%m`, `%%%m` is `%` plus the month.

```
var rx1 = new Regex("(?<=(?:^|[^%])(?:%%)*)(?:(%M)|(%m))");
```

and

```
var rx2 = new Regex("(?<=(?:^|[^%])(?:%%)*)%[Mm]");
```

Comment: While all answers work for the problem, I've marked this answer as correct answer because it contains a short and readable way of replacing the characters, same for the comment under the OP which uses String.Join and String.Select for replacing

Answer (score 0):

For ASCII letters, the 6ᵗʰ bit can be used to switch between upper and lower case:

```
var s = "%Y %m %d | %H:%M:%S";
s = string.Concat(s.Select(c => (c | 32) == 'm' ? (char)(c ^ 32) : c));
```

Comment: @xanatos I have few more similar bit operation answers but can't remember what were the questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667802/what-is-the-algorithm-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number/41122035#41122035