# C# Excel get column letter

Tags: c#, excel

In our Excel table, there are calendar weeks given in row 2 (2D = 37, 2E = 38, 2F = 39,...), but we need to figure out which number has which column letter. Something like:

```
get (Column Letter) where (Value in row 2 = 39)
```

in this example we would get an "F" back, as 39 is in 2F

But we can´t find anything in the web that could help us

Comment: Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667802/what-is-the-algorithm-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number)

Comment: You may need to explain better - what is 2D & why does it equal 37. 2D cannot be a cell reference, because the column letter should be first - do you mean 37 is in cell D2. If "2D" is a string, then you could use the Substring method to get the last character? Also, how are you accessing the excel table - Microsoft interop, epplus, some other library?

Comment: We use interop, and yeah i meant number 37 is in Cell D2, so if we ask in what column 37 is, we want to get "D"