# How to get index from Cell Reference?

Tags: c#, excel

This code below works perfectly fine for column A-Z.  but it does not work for excel that exceeds a-z to aa,ab,... when z col exceed again it returns index from 0....

```
private static int CellReferenceToIndex(Cell cell)
{
    int index = 0;
    string reference = cell.CellReference.ToString().ToUpper();
    foreach (char ch in reference)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(ch))
        {
            int value = (int)ch - (int)'A';
            index = (index == 0) ? value : ((index + 1) * 26) + value;
        }
        else
            return index;
    }
        return index;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667802/what-is-the-algorithm-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the algorithm to convert an Excel Column Letter into its Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667802/what-is-the-algorithm-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, minor modification

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reference )) throw new ArgumentNullException("reference");

            reference = reference.ToUpperInvariant();

            int index= 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < reference.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(reference[i]))
                {
                    index *= 26;
                    index += (reference [i] - 'A' + 1);
                }
            }

            return index-1;
```