# Simple way to access to Excel cell by its "coordination" eg "B7" instead of [7,1]

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have Excel file in which I want to fill data. The cells may be re-arranged and will be given in a list in format like "B7", "C5", "G8", etc...

So I would like to access the sheet by these coordinations.

I have this code:

```
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

try
{
    //Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;

    //Open existing workbook
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(filename);
    oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];

    //This works good: (but need something similar)
    oSheet.Cells[7, 2] = "The cell content";

    //Need to access to cell like this:
    oSheet.Cells["B7"] = "The cell content";


    oWB.Close();
}
catch (Exception theException)
{
    String errorMessage;
    errorMessage = "Error: ";
    errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
    errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
    errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);

    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a column number (e.g. 127) into an Excel column (e.g. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-e-g-127-into-an-excel-column-e-g-aa)

Comment: Sorry, previous link is incorrect (is the other way around), this seems to be the correct one [What is the algorithm to convert an Excel Column Letter into its Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667802/what-is-the-algorithm-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number)

Comment: Can't you just use `oSheet.Range("B7")= "The cell content"`

Comment: Tried this. but gets the Error: Non-invocable member '_Worksheet.Range[object, object]' cannot be used like a method. @DS_London

Comment: It will be my secandery choise, but prefere stright  function. @Cleptus

Comment: @Ron *Non-invocable member '_Worksheet.Range[object, object]' cannot be used like a method.* then use square brackets

Comment: Syntax:   oSheet.Range["B7"] = "The cell content";    I'm getting the error: Property or indexer '_Worksheet.Range[object, object]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only; @Selvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Range` interface, you can access cell(s) by an address

```
// one cell
var range = oSheet.Range["B8"];
range.Value = "The cell content";

// more cells like B8, B9, C8, C9
var range = oSheet.Range["B8", "C9"];
range.Value = "The cell content";
```

Comment: Make it simple oSheet.Range["B7"].Value = "The cell content"

Comment: @rotabor that's not simple at all and a performance trap. Every call in COM interop is a cross-process call. If you want to work with the same cell or range, repeating `.Range["B8"]` causes a slow cross-process call over and over again, for no reason.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's a gold thought, truly. But it's the general consideration applicable to every complex object not only called through COM. In the question, there are no repeatable calls of the same cell or range. More probable, reading/writing on many cells is preposed.

Comment: @rotabor no, it's experience from my VB6 days. What you proposed offers no benefits  (the "simplicity" is subjective") but it *does* introduce problems.