# How to generate an array of 2 char length of alphanumeric characters

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to generate an array of 2 character length of alphanumeric (0-9, A-Z) characters without having to hardcode all of the values. 
Ex output: 00, 01,..., 09, 90, 91,..., 99, A0, A1,..., A9,AA,..., ZZ

I found a link to generate an array of letters with less work, but I am still unsure of how to do this for a 2D array. I'm new to working with multidimensional arrays. Thanks!

[Generating an array of letters in the alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314466/generating-an-array-of-letters-in-the-alphabet-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you show us what you want the array to look like?

Comment: Hint: char a = (char)65;//this will give you 'A'

Comment: Using loops or linq it's fairly easy. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Maxqueue eww. I think a better piece of advice would be saying that `'A'+1 == 'B'`, `'A'+2 == 'C'`, etc. I urge you to never use `(char)65` in your code. Ever.

Comment: @juharr I created a regular array of the characters, I just need the array to be 2D with the same characters: public const char[] FirstChars = new char[]
        {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' };

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  Think of a 2D array as a table where the first dimension is the row number and the second is the column.  You need to tell use how many rows and columns you expect and what values should be in each cell.

Comment: Can you print the sample output you are looking for? should it be like this: "1A", "1B" , ...

Comment: Or maybe you could tell use what you plan to use this 2D array for.  This might be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Yes output would be 00,01,10,...99,A0,A1,...A9,..AA...ZZ, etc

Comment: @juharr I'm sorry- output would be 00,01,10,...99,A0,A1,...A9,..AA...ZZ, etc

Comment: That doesn't look like a 2D array, it looks like an array of two character length strings.  Do you mean {{'0','0'},{'0','1'},{'1','0'},...{'9','9'},{'A','0'},{'A','1'},....{'Z','Z'}}.  Basically the Cartesian product of the set of all alpha-numeric characters with itself?

Comment: @juharr you are correct, I was mistaken in needing a 2D array and I see that now. I need an array of two character length strings of the Cartesian product of the set of alphanumeric characters. I'm sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cartesian product of all alpha numeric characters as two character strings then you can use Linq and do the following.

```
string alphanumeric = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
string[] allAlphaNumericPairs = (from a in alphanumeric
                                 from b in alphanumeric
                                 select new string(new []{a,b})).ToArray();
```