# QuickBooks Retrieve of Customers Fails

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have this code:

```
protected readonly IMsgSetRequest RequestMsgSet = null;
protected IMsgSetResponse ResponseMsgSet = null;

public string GetAllCustomer(bool IsActiveOnly = true)
{

    RequestMsgSet.ClearRequests();
    ICustomerQuery CustomerQueryRq = RequestMsgSet.AppendCustomerQueryRq();

    if (IsActiveOnly)
    {
        if (CustomerQueryRq != null)
            CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ActiveStatus.SetValue(
                ENActiveStatus.asActiveOnly);
    }
    else {
        CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ActiveStatus.SetValue(ENActiveStatus.asAll);
    }
    ResponseMsgSet = SessionManager.DoRequests(RequestMsgSet);
    return(ResponseMsgSet.ToXMLString());
}

Console.WriteLine(GetAllCustomer());
```

It returns this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<CustomerQueryRs requestID="0" statusCode="1000" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="There has been an internal error when processing the request." />
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

I suspect that the DoRequests runs out of memory as I have 110,000 customers.

How can I confirm that DoRequests is running out of memory?

How can I rewrite this code to use less memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ICustomerQuery](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html)

You can get data with filtering's such as: name range (a-i, j-r than s-z) filter, date range filter, name starts with filter and other some filters as well.

Also this can be used to get only the things you want like: **FullName** and **AccountNumber**.

In this way you may consume less memory usage. Have a look at below sample code:

```
public IList<CustomerModelQB> GetAllCustomer(string fromName = "a", string toName = "z", bool IsActiveOnly = true)
    {
        RequestMsgSet.ClearRequests();
        ICustomerQuery CustomerQueryRq = RequestMsgSet.AppendCustomerQueryRq();

        if (IsActiveOnly)
        {
            if (CustomerQueryRq != null)
                CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ActiveStatus.SetValue(
                    ENActiveStatus.asActiveOnly);
        }
        else
            CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ActiveStatus.SetValue(ENActiveStatus.asAll);

        //CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.MaxReturned.SetValue(3);

        //Set field value for FromName
        CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ORNameFilter.NameRangeFilter.FromName.SetValue(fromName);
        //Set field value for ToName
        CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.CustomerListFilter.ORNameFilter.NameRangeFilter.ToName.SetValue(toName);

        CustomerQueryRq.IncludeRetElementList.Add("FullName");
        CustomerQueryRq.IncludeRetElementList.Add("AccountNumber");
        ResponseMsgSet = SessionManager.DoRequests(RequestMsgSet);
        return WalkCustomerQuery(ResponseMsgSet);
    }
```

Further you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314466/generating-an-array-of-letters-in-the-alphabet) question for alphabetical breakout of things.

Comment: This code is good for filtering the data after it is retrieved, but the problem is that response does not come back with data.

Comment: The revised code reduces memory usage.  I did not use the fromName/toName logic.  If you work on adding an iterator then add it as a new answer.