# Random Directory Generator Working With numbers but won't create anything when I include letters and i get no errors

Tags: c#, random, directory

```
for (int i = 0; i < WindowForm.GalaxySize; i++)
            {
                string CGenSystem;

                string A1 = rnd.Next(1, 3).ToString();
                string A2 = rnd.Next(1, 3).ToString();

                string B1 = rnd.Next(1, 3).ToString();
                string B2 = rnd.Next(1, 3).ToString();

                string C1 = rnd.Next(1, 3).ToString();
                string C2 = rnd.Next(1, 3).ToString();

                if(Int32.Parse(A1) == 1)
                {
                    A1 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    A1 = rnd.Next(1, 27).ToString();

                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 1) { A1 = "A"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 2) { A1 = "B"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 3) { A1 = "C"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 4) { A1 = "D"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 5) { A1 = "E"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 6) { A1 = "F"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 7) { A1 = "G"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 8) { A1 = "H"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 9) { A1 = "I"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 10) { A1 = "J"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 11) { A1 = "K"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 12) { A1 = "L"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 13) { A1 = "M"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 14) { A1 = "N"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 15) { A1 = "O"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 16) { A1 = "P"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 17) { A1 = "Q"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 18) { A1 = "R"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 19) { A1 = "S"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 20) { A1 = "T"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 21) { A1 = "U"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 22) { A1 = "V"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 23) { A1 = "W"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 24) { A1 = "X"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 25) { A1 = "Y"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A1) == 26) { A1 = "Z"; }
                }

                if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 1)
                {
                    A2 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    A2 = rnd.Next(1, 27).ToString();

                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 1) { A2 = "A"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 2) { A2 = "B"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 3) { A2 = "C"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 4) { A2 = "D"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 5) { A2 = "E"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 6) { A2 = "F"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 7) { A2 = "G"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 8) { A2 = "H"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 9) { A2 = "I"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 10) { A2 = "J"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 11) { A2 = "K"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 12) { A2 = "L"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 13) { A2 = "M"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 14) { A2 = "N"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 15) { A2 = "O"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 16) { A2 = "P"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 17) { A2 = "Q"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 18) { A2 = "R"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 19) { A2 = "S"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 20) { A2 = "T"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 21) { A2 = "U"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 22) { A2 = "V"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 23) { A2 = "W"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 24) { A2 = "X"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 25) { A2 = "Y"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(A2) == 26) { A2 = "Z"; return; }
                }

                if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 1)
                {
                    B1 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    B1 = rnd.Next(1, 27).ToString();

                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 1) { B1 = "A"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 2) { B1 = "B"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 3) { B1 = "C"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 4) { B1 = "D"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 5) { B1 = "E"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 6) { B1 = "F"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 7) { B1 = "G"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 8) { B1 = "H"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 9) { B1 = "I"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 10) { B1 = "J"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 11) { B1 = "K"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 12) { B1 = "L"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 13) { B1 = "M"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 14) { B1 = "N"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 15) { B1 = "O"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 16) { B1 = "P"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 17) { B1 = "Q"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 18) { B1 = "R"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 19) { B1 = "S"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 20) { B1 = "T"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 21) { B1 = "U"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 22) { B1 = "V"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 23) { B1 = "W"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 24) { B1 = "X"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 25) { B1 = "Y"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B1) == 26) { B1 = "Z"; return; }
                }

                if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 1)
                {
                    B2 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    B2 = rnd.Next(1, 27).ToString();

                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 1) { B2 = "A"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 2) { B2 = "B"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 3) { B2 = "C"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 4) { B2 = "D"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 5) { B2 = "E"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 6) { B2 = "F"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 7) { B2 = "G"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 8) { B2 = "H"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 9) { B2 = "I"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 10) { B2 = "J"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 11) { B2 = "K"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 12) { B2 = "L"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 13) { B2 = "M"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 14) { B2 = "N"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 15) { B2 = "O"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 16) { B2 = "P"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 17) { B2 = "Q"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 18) { B2 = "R"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 19) { B2 = "S"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 20) { B2 = "T"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 21) { B2 = "U"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 22) { B2 = "V"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 23) { B2 = "W"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 24) { B2 = "X"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 25) { B2 = "Y"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(B2) == 26) { B2 = "Z"; return; }
                }

                if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 1)
                {
                    C1 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    C1 = rnd.Next(1, 27).ToString();

                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 1) { C1 = "A"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 2) { C1 = "B"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 3) { C1 = "C"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 4) { C1 = "D"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 5) { C1 = "E"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 6) { C1 = "F"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 7) { C1 = "G"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 8) { C1 = "H"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 9) { C1 = "I"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 10) { C1 = "J"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 11) { C1 = "K"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 12) { C1 = "L"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 13) { C1 = "M"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 14) { C1 = "N"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 15) { C1 = "O"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 16) { C1 = "P"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 17) { C1 = "Q"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 18) { C1 = "R"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 19) { C1 = "S"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 20) { C1 = "T"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 21) { C1 = "U"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 22) { C1 = "V"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 23) { C1 = "W"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 24) { C1 = "X"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 25) { C1 = "Y"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C1) == 26) { C1 = "Z"; return; }
                }

                if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 1)
                {
                    C2 = rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    C2 = rnd.Next(1, 27).ToString();

                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 1) { C2 = "A"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 2) { C2 = "B"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 3) { C2 = "C"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 4) { C2 = "D"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 5) { C2 = "E"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 6) { C2 = "F"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 7) { C2 = "G"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 8) { C2 = "H"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 9) { C2 = "I"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 10) { C2 = "J"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 11) { C2 = "K"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 12) { C2 = "L"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 13) { C2 = "M"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 14) { C2 = "N"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 15) { C2 = "O"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 16) { C2 = "P"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 17) { C2 = "Q"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 18) { C2 = "R"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 19) { C2 = "S"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 20) { C2 = "T"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 21) { C2 = "U"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 22) { C2 = "V"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 23) { C2 = "W"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 24) { C2 = "X"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 25) { C2 = "Y"; return; }
                    if (Int32.Parse(C2) == 26) { C2 = "Z"; return; }
                }

                CGenSystem = A1+A2+"-"+B1+B2+"-"+C1+C2; ;

                if(!Directory.Exists(@"GameData\\GameSaves\\"+WindowForm.GalaxyName+"\\GalaxyData\\"+CGenSystem))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"GameData\\GameSaves\\" + WindowForm.GalaxyName + "\\GalaxyData\\" + CGenSystem);
                }
            }
```

So i have been coding a game in which a galaxy is randomly generated, The Star Systems names are determined by this code below, When setting the first 6 Strings to equal rnd.next(1,2).ToString(); I get all the systems generated as numbers which works without any problems, I did not intend to have them as only numbers they have a 50/50 chance of being a letter, for some reason when i fixed it so that it does this, now when it begins generating it makes NO folders under GalaxyData and there are absolutely NO errors detected.
This is really confusing me, am i coding it wrong or is this something with C#?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I have been trying to Debug this for pas 3 hours which is why i turnded to Stack Overflow =/

Comment: Since your chance of getting a letter isn't 50% anyway you could greatly simplify things by just putting all numbers and chars in one array and pick randomly from it.

Comment: What's `GameData` in your path? Its any shared folder or anything else? Because its not started from any hard drive disk letter like `@"C:/GameData/....`

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing wrong with the rest of your path?

Comment: Yeah, ill try that

Comment: Nah, nothing wrong with the path, it works fine when i have to just pick from numbers

Comment: This is the full path if it wasn't going into TBD folders C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Galactic Field\Galactic Field\bin\Debug\GameData\GameSaves\New Galaxy\GalaxyData

Comment: try giving full path starting from your drive letter instead of just starting from `@"GameData...."`

Answer (score 0):

Even if your actual issue is clearly somewhere else, I'd like to show you how you can greatly simplify your program:

```
// create an array of all your random digits and characters
// ... if you want to put a higher chance on any, just add them multiple times
char[] alphanum = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray(); //***

for (int i = 0; i < WindowForm.GalaxySize; i++)
{
    // define an array to contain the parts of your random name
    string[] nameparts = new string[6];

    // loop as many times as necessary to fill your nameparts array
    for (int j = 0; j < nameparts.Length; j++)
    {
        // pick a random character from your alphanum array
        int c = rnd.Next(0, alphanum.Length - 1);

        // ... and store it in the nameparts array
        nameparts[j] = alphanum[c].ToString();
    }

    // combine the name parts in the desired format
    string CGenSystem = string.Format("{0}{1}-{2}{3}-{4}{5}", nameparts);

    // Use System.IO.Path.Combine to handle creating path strings
    string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Galactic Field\bin\Debug\GameData\GameSaves", WindowForm.GalaxyName, "GalaxyData", CGenSystem);
}
```

---

***) courtesy of [Generating an array of letters in the alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314475/205233)