# generate alphabet from current culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, currentculture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quickest way to enumerate the alphabet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208688/quickest-way-to-enumerate-the-alphabet-in-c-sharp)
>   [Howto enumerate the LOCALIZED alphabet in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676692/howto-enumerate-the-localized-alphabet-in-c)

Is there any way in .net to generate the alphabet for the current culture? For example in English - ABCDE.... If the culture is Russian, generate such. I am working with the .net 4.5 framework.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2208688/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208688/quickest-way-to-enumerate-the-alphabet-in-c-sharp) and [stackoverflow.com/questions/5676692/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676692/howto-enumerate-the-localized-alphabet-in-c) should point you into the direction - this may be a possible duplicate here

Comment: There is nothing in .NET that will generate an alphabet for you. You have to implement such library yourself. The links given by Basti M can help you. Don't forget that some cultures don't use alphabets (Chinese for example).

Answer (score -5):

I don't think so but you can make a function for it

Comment: This response is so generic and unspecific that it probably applies to > 90% of all SO questions; it won't help the OP at all.

Comment: sorry I'll try not doing answers like this again