# Iterate Through Unicode Ranges

Tags: vb.net, unicode

I want to get the range of characters between any two Unicode points.

This below doesn't work in VB.NET and doesn't give any hints on how to convert it to use Unicode instead.

```c#
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    yield return c;
}
```

[The above is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2208705/4752777)

Converted it looks like this :

```
For c As Char = "A"c To "Z"c
    Yield c
Next
```

But this causes an error "*'For' loop control variable cannot be of type 'Char' because the type does not support the required operators.*"

Say I want to get Basic Latin, is there any way to do it like below?

```
For c As Char = U+0000 To U+007F
    Yield c
Next
```

I'm struggling to find anything on this specific subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET unfortunately does not treat chars the same way C# do. A char is actually just a number (known as a *character code*) that represents letter, so to a computer it actually makes sense that you would be able to use them in a loop.

However, for it to work in VB.NET you would have to convert the chars into integers first to be able to use them in a loop, then convert the integer in each iteration *back* into a `Char`:

```
For i As Integer = AscW("A"c) To AscW("Z"c)
    Dim c As Char = ChrW(i)
    Yield c
Next
```

As for your second example, Unicode code points are represented in the form `U+####`. The `####` part is a hexadecimal number, which can be written in VB.NET in the form `&H####`. To the compiler a hexadecimal number is just a normal number, so all you need to do is to change your loop to:

```
For i As Integer = &H0000 To &H007F
    Dim c As Char = ChrW(i)
    Yield c
Next
```

- [**`AscW()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey48db8z(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**`ChrW()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But that doesn't work for Unicode ranges, if i put U+0000 to U+007F or 0000 to 007F, i get U U and 0 0 respectively.
How would you do it with the range code values?

Comment: @VampireMonkey : Just finished updating my answer with that. :)

Comment: @VampireMonkey : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is by using [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range). Here's a one-liner:

```
Enumerable.Range(AscW("A"c), AscW("Z"c) - AscW("A"c) + 1).Select(Function(i) ChrW(i))
```

You can put it in a function like this:

```
Public Function CharRange(first As Char, last As Char) As IEnumerable(Of Char)
    Return Enumerable.Range(AscW(first), AscW(last) - AscW(first) + 1).Select(Function(i) ChrW(i))
End Function
```

For the Unicode version, you'd need to use Integers instead of Chars:

```
Public Function CharRange(first As Integer, last As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of Char)
    Return Enumerable.Range(first, last - first + 1).Select(Function(i) ChrW(i))
End Function
```

Also, now that we have an *Integer version*, you can replace the first function with this shorter version:

```
Public Function CharRange(first As Char, last As Char) As IEnumerable(Of Char)
    Return CharRange(AscW(first), AscW(last))
End Function
```

**Sample usage:**

```
'Dim combined As String = String.Join("", CharRange("A"c, "Z"c))
Dim combined As String = String.Join("", CharRange(&H41, &H5A))
Console.WriteLine(combined)
```

**Output:**

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ