# Select Unicode character subset by culture

Tags: c#, unicode, cultureinfo

I'd like to iterate over a character list. The character list should be a subset of a Unicode character set. Unicode have a lot of codes, and AFAIK Unicode includes all characters for all cultures.

What I want is to select a certain subset of Unicode characters depending on a specific culture, since a specific culture doesn't use all Unicode characters.

Is this possible?

I'm trying to draw a set of characters for OpenGL texture generation. In this way I can render font glyphs with OpenGL using a texture (very simple, enought fast). I'm already supporting ASCII character set, since there are less than 256 displayable characters, but with Unicode I need to select a subset of characters, otherwise the resulting OpenGL texture will be unmanageable.

What I'm trying is to select a subset of Unicode characters depending on the requested culture. I cannot think about another top level filter except the culture.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would do with this information? (Depending on what you are trying to do, determining the characters on the current keyboard layout might be an alternate approach.)

Comment: This is a bit dangerous.  Arabic or Japanese for example will readily transcribe a Western word using Latin letters.  Similarly, Japanese uses a lot of Chinese characters.  Unicode mappings are otherwise largely grouped by language or usage, just look up the tables.  http://www.unicodemap.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be fair to say, a specific culture does not use most Unicode Characters.

Check out [the current standard](http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html). I don't think there is a direct correlation between Cultures and Scripts, this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252662/localization-how-to-map-culture-info-to-a-script-name-or-unicode-character-rang) touches on the problem.